# Getting this exception MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php when I try to use Auth middleware in a POST route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Here is my Blade syntax:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('favorite')}}" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_medicine" value="{{$medicine->id}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add To My List</button>
</form>
```

Then the route:

```
 Route::post('/favorite', ['as' => 'favorite', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'MedicineController@makeFavorite'] );
```

Controller Method:

```
public function makeFavorite(Request $request)
    {
       return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the rendered output of your form and verify that the action that is rendered matches the expected `/favorite`? Also check the output of `php artisan routes` and make sure you don't have any other routes named "favorite".

Comment: everything works fine if I remove Auth middleware from the Route!

Comment: Could it be that you are posting the form while not being authenticated? Also, did you modify 'auth' middleware at all?

Comment: Just a guess here, but I'm guessing you aren't authenticated and you are being redirected to the login page, which has not been registered.

Comment: I assumed that the route passes to the auth controller and after login it would submit the form. was it right?

Comment: login routes are registerd.

Comment: Just found that after successful login it actually send a GET request to the controller and that's the reason behind the exception. any workaround ?

Comment: Change `Route::post` to `Route::get`?

Comment: @RaihanMahmud so maybe make it so that the GET request returns the page with the form and then the user can re-submit the form which would be POST

Comment: yes. That should solve the problem @vonec.. Thnaks a lot